# Jquery displays link text instead of image

Tags: javascript, wordpress, text, hyperlink

for my wordpress site I have replaced the bottom paging-navigation with a load more function.

This used to say the text "load more" but I have replaced it with an image, or at least that is the plan.

The jquery is just showing the link to the file, instead of actually showing it.
I just can't figure it out, anybody out there who can lend me a hand ?
The piece in the index.php that is what I'm trying to fix:

```
'plus' => esc_js( plugins_url( '/images/plus.png', __FILE__ ) ),
```

located in this bit:

```
    $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    wp_enqueue_script( '-load-more', plugins_url( '/js/loadmore.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '20131010', true );
    wp_localize_script( '-load-more', '_load_more', array(
        'current_page' => esc_js( $paged ),
        'max_pages' => esc_js( $max ),
        'ajaxurl' => esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ),
        'plus' => esc_js( plugins_url( '/images/plus.png', __FILE__ ) ),
        'loading_img' => esc_js( plugins_url( '/images/ajax-loader.gif', __FILE__ ) )
    ) );
}
```

Used in the javascript here :

```
if ( next_page <= max_pages ) {
    $( '.paging-navigation' ).html( '<div class="nav-links"><a class="load_more" href="#">' + _load_more.plus + '</a><img class="load_more_img" style="display: none;" src="' + _load_more.loading_img + '" alt="Loading..." /></div>' );
}
```

The website is located here: [www.hellodolly.be](http://www.hellodolly.be/)

So the goal is to get the link to the image, which is correct, to actually display as the image.

Comment: we have no idea what `_load_more` is in your javascript. Also problem description is not easy to understand. Please provide a [mcve]. Website links are useless as that link will rot not displaying the problem in the question and questions should be self contained

Answer (score 0):

You have `display: none;` style for img with class `load_more_img`. That's why loading image isn't showed (As I understand you want to show it after click "show more"). Also you render `_load_more.plus` value which is path of the image to the content of `<a></a>` tag (don't know why you need this, but it's strange).

After all I think you want to make `<a></a>` element with image in backround from `_load_more.plus` path and with `href` with path to open more items. And when items are still loading you want to show `load_more_img`. In this case you should make some refactoring of your code.

**EDITED**:

Some changes for this piece of code. You need to add click handler for `load_more` link for dynamic async loading of new items. May be smth like this:

```
 $('.load_more').click(function() {
             $.get('<url_to_get_more_items>').done(function(data) {
                     var html = compileTemplate(data); // use Handlebars or Mustache as templates engine, or just make response from server as ready for use html
                     $('<items_container>).append(html);
                     });
             });
```

Also you need to  add `img` tag with all data inside of `<a></a>` tag to show `show_more` image. Result:

```
if ( next_page <= max_pages ) {
    $( '.paging-navigation' ).html( '<div class="nav-links"><a class="load_more" href="#"><img class="some-awesome-class-name" src="' + _load_more.plus + '" alt="Show more"></a><img class="load_more_img" style="display: none;" src="' + _load_more.loading_img + '" alt="Loading..." /></div>' );
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes this is what I want to do. Sorry if the description isnt 100% clear, fairly new to all of this. Indeed, I would want the <a></a> element with image (a black circle with a plus in it) to be always visible, from the path provided in the _load_more.plus. When clicked upon it, the script should run and the load more image (spinning circle) appears.

So refactoring of the code... where do I start, do I need to put the link to the image inside the <a></a> tags ?

Comment: I fixed it ! Simple really, but once you have the solution it always is. 
'main_text' => esc_js( __( '<img class="plus" src="http://www.hellodolly.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/plus.png"  />   in the index page did the trick. When I call the main_text like this:  $( '.paging-navigation' ).html( '<div class="nav-links"><a class="load_more" href="#">' + _load_more.main_text + '</a>   it works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I've mentioned, additional img tag. Congratulations.